# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, tomcat, eclipse-jdt

Running Tomcat 7 through eclipse
The error reported is:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:341)
```

I have tried both jasper-jdt-6.0.13.jar and tomcat-6.0.16-jasper-jdt.jar and both report the same error. In a way I shouldn't be surprised because I ran:

```
jar tf tomcat-6.0.16-jasper-jdt.jar
```

and it doesn't have the class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult in it. But this site http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/Downloadtomcat6016jasperjdtjar.htm says it does!!
Can someone tell me what the correct jar file is and where to get it from?
It seems to be a recurring theme. http://www.findjar.com lists a number of jars that purport to have this class - but do not.

OK, Found it in jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.23.jar

Comment: combining 6 and 7 won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.23.jar