# Runtime exception - Datanucleus enhancer

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, datanucleus

In order to trigger the `Datanucleus enhancer`, I needed to do a dummy modify the Persistable class/Entity then save it again. 
However when triggered, throws/logs this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(Lorg/datanucleus/PersistenceConfiguration;Lorg/datanucleus/ClassLoaderResolver;)V
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:159)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:172)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:150)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1157)
    ... 7 more
```

Although the datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.1 is in the Maven classpath and also in the WEB-INF/folder.

What can be causing this error if not missing libraries?

Comment: One solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200414/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror says that the fix will be including "jasper-compiler-jdt" I'm not sure whether this one should be included for GAE

Comment: Datanucleus is very capable of running without Jasper components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you believe everything you read on the internet? What has jasper-compiler got to do with DataNucleus enhancement? Answer : nothing. That post was about some method missing from some Jasper class ... which you don't have.

You simply are using inconsistent versions of "datanucleus-enhancer" and "datanucleus-core". If you were using Maven you wouldn't have the issue, but since you aren't you can see easily enough [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.0.1/datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.1.pom) that if using datanucleus-enhancer 3.0.1 then you need datanucleus-core 3.0.x also. After all that is what NoSuchMethodError implies also ... some thing is not present in the CLASSPATH. The packaged DataNucleus zip distributions always provide ALL consistent files, so you haven't used one of those either

Comment: I'm using Maven. I believe I have defined to use v 3.0.1 for the Datanucleus dependencies.

Comment: So why have you got a reference to OMFContext then ? which disappeared from DataNucleus a long time ago. Your classpath is wrong.

Comment: Well, I created a new Eclipse project moving from my original Maven project, and adding the dependencies manually in the CLASSPATH and in the WEB-INF\lib folder. When I try to do POST I get this error: Persistent class \"com.myapp.model.Account\" has no table in the database,

Comment: And from the logs says: "NullPointerException: ormLibs cannot be null"

Comment: Which has got what to do with enhancement? This question is about enhancement

Comment: yah I know sorry about that, that's why I just put it as a side comment. Anyway, its really hard to make Datanucleus Rest API to work, which is the whole point of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Also, I think the subject is still there the problem is about enhancement too, because I'm still trying to deal with the issue only that instead of using Maven, I just manually added the lib and deps.